# Read and write from S3 server (ECS) using Python (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-ecs

I need to read a fixed width file from S3 server which is an ECS and then convert it into a CSV write back to the S3 server.

I am trying using smart_open library from this link https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/ but my code is giving error

```
File "create_csv_ecs.py", line 11, in <module>
from smart_open import open
ImportError: No module named smart_open
```

However when i do not user smart_open then it says path does not exists.

My code is like below it working when i run it on local but hwne i tried our SPARK server and then try to read file from S3 it gives error

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

from smart_open import open
import csv
import re
import sys

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Convert CSV - Python")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)


print ("Hello Spark")

sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "access_key")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "sceret_key")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "end_point")

fname_in = 's3a://bucket/test_file.txt'
fname_out = 's3a://bucket/test_file_output.txt'

cols = [(0, 1), (1, 6), (6, 9), (9, 10), (10, 15), (15, 25), (25, 28), (28, 38)]

with open(fname_in) as fin, open(fname_out, 'wt') as fout:

    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    header = next(reader)  # read header
    print(header)
    acc_period = list()
    o = [num for num in re.findall('\d*', str(header)) if num]
    date = sorted(o)[0]
    print(o)
    print(date)
    year, month, day = date[:4], date[4:6], date[6:]
    acc_period.extend(('{0:03d}'.format(int(month)), '{0:03d}'.format(int(month) - 1)))
    print(acc_period)

    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n")

    writer.writerow(["FLAG", "CODE", "SOURCE", "STATUS", "UNIT", "ID"
                 , "LINE", "GROUP"])

    for line in fin:
        line = line.rstrip()  # removing the '\n' and other trailing whitespaces
        row = []  # init -- empty list
        data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]
        # print("data:",data[16])
        # Excluding rows where account not start with 4 or 5 and (int(str(data[11])) in acc_period)
        writer.writerow(data)
sc.stop()
sys.exit()
```

My SPARK server version is 2.3.0

sample file will look like below

```
HGLOABCD8PSGL_ZXFH J20190603NXT_APAC
D30056747PRD0091921170811405ACTUAL    ACTUAL    6222020190110001508014
D30056747PRD0091921170811405ACTUAL    ACTUAL    6222020190110001508014
```

Comment: How many rows have your files?..I think you should use boto3

Comment: You're not actually doing any manipulation in `pyspark`. Is there a particular reason why aren't you loading the data directly such as `df = sc.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option('delimiter', ',').load('s3://mybucket/my/directory/file.csv')`?

Comment: @Giovani - it could be 10-14 GB file so lots of rows

Comment: @napolean - well i have 2 parts of my requirement 1 is to create CSV like above and other is doing aggregation on generated CSV where i am using pyspark.
but if you can elaborate your comment like how i can use the above load method in converting the CSV then it will be helpful